# Cut the string before the first space

Tags: sql, shell

I'm trying to cut the string before the first space as I want to get the value returned from the DB request assigned to MINOR_VER variable. 
The returned string is `3 1 row selected (overall time 6731 usec; server time 1281 usec)`

and I only need **3** as an output.

My approach is to get the string and pass it to cut, but so far I couldn't reach the goal.

```
MINOR_VER_QUERY="select count(*) from $DB_SCHEMA.RPT where CASE_UUID='3'"

MINOR_VER=$(echo `hdbsql -a -n $HOST -i $INSTANCE -u $DB_USER -p $DB_PWD $MINOR_VER_QUERY` | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

hdbsql is hana database sql cli to create a db connecntion.

Comment: Try : firstchar=${MINOR_VER:0:1}; echo $firstchar

Comment: @JNevill thanks for pointing to `-x` flag, with this one data comes in a cleaner way, if you formulate it as an answer below, I can also choose it as a right one.

Comment: @Ren I killed my commends and added as an answer. Happy to hear that helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `-x` flag available for hdbsql CLI that will drop the appended statistics from the returned result set. You may also find the `-quiet` flag to be helpful too. [More info on available flags here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.04/en-US/c24d054bbb571014b253ac5d6943b5bd.html)

Instead:

```
MINOR_VER=$(hdbsql -x -quiet -a -n $HOST -i $INSTANCE -u $DB_USER -p $DB_PWD $MINOR_VER_QUERY)
```